# Java long string of nulls

Tags: java, bluetooth, null, buffer

I read bytes[] from bluetooth inside a while loop to receive bytes then write them to an output file , but i see a long string of nulls added to each line 
why does that happen? how can i solve that?

```
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    String message;
    try {
    do {
    input.read(buffer);
    fil.write(buffer);
    fil.flush();
    }while(//some condition);
    }
```

this code is written inside a thread.
output file:
value +"long string of null"

update:the data written on the file is not formatted as i send them, how can i view them as they were send?

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming that `read(buffer);` always reads `1024` bytes, when it will read *up to* 1024 bytes. It will return the amount of bytes read, so change your code to

```
int bytes = input.read(buffer);
fil.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do somthing like this:

```
    int count;
    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fil.write(buffer , 0, count);
    }
```